# Using system environment variables in spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, spyder

I have a program coded in Python 2 that I need to run and I would like to run it in spyder via anaconda software.
The issue is that to run the program via the terminal I had to previously add in my system environment variables two new variables:

1. one folder in the computer where some required packages are
2. a variable with the ip address for the required license.

Although I have these variables define and the program runs without issues in the terminal. When I run it in spyder there is an error because it is not using those variables.

How can I fix this? I head something about anaconda creates virtual environments that is not loading those variables but I could not understand anything else. For example if I use pycharm, outside anaconda, it also works flawlessly.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. The best I can say is that variables aren't to do with anaconda environments

Comment: If you want to run the script in spyder, the easiest way would be to just declare the file path as an actual variable and not an environment variable

Comment: So spyder does not load the system variables, they must be imported in the beginning of the script is that right?

Comment: I don't believe that spyder cares about environment variables that are defined outside. The way it constructs its own environment is quite complicated because of IPython and a global namespace between the console and your script. Having re-read your question a few more times, I think I get what you're asking. My _guess_ is that this is folly, or at least bug-prone, but it's just that; a guess. I'll have to leave it to others to answer

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove the second question at the end, btw. Your post should ideally focus on one issue

Answer (score 7):

I believe Anaconda offers instructions on setting environment variables but that approach seemed complicated.

Setting an environment variable no longer seems to be an option in Spyder.

As a workaround Spyder does allow you to specify a startup file:
`Preferences` -> `IPython Console` -> `Startup`

In the startup file you just run something like:

```
import os
os.environ['my_var'] = 'my_value'
os.environ['test'] = 'test_value'
```

Every time you start a new ipython console this code will run.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in the Tools menu that let's you check/insert/update/remove the currently active environment variables in Spyder (pic for reference).

[Spyder Environment Variables Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwafV.png)

Edit: Regarding your *PS* question, when you install packages (through pip?) you are doing so through the currently active Python installation, which you can check by running

```
python -V
```

Therefore, if you intend to install a package in multiple installations, you need to use the corresponding package manager executable.

Comment: I already added the required variables in there but, unfortunately, the problem persisted.

Comment: Let me have a further look then

Comment: Btw, are you using IPython console, or running the script?

Comment: Are your environment variables set on the system or user level? Because I just did some tests, and Spyder only recognizes user-level environment variables.

Comment: I have tried it now defining them as user variables but still does not import. I do run but it always opens the IPython console. I think I will just use VSCode or pycharm. I was just interested in spyder because its GUI is very similar to MATLAB with which I feel much more confortable.

Comment: I used Matlab during university, and I tried using Spyder, but I just can't adapt. Personally, I love the customizability of VS Code, and I'm pushing the rest of my Data Science team to migrate to VS Code. Hope you enjoy it.

Comment: Interesting. The option shown in the screenshot doesn't exist on my Spyder drop-down menu but it's what I was looking for. Instead I have to set the environment on the command line before opening Spyder from that same command line. Even this won't work if I use the Spyder setting "execute in external system terminal" but oh well.

Comment: It worked for me but I had to restart Spyder after I saved the new environmental variables.

Answer (score -1):

That dropdown menu is on Spyder 5.1.5

[image: Screnshot]